# Are functions inside functions recreated each time I call the outer function, if the inner function doesn't use any variable of the outer one?

Tags: javascript, performance, function, scope

For example, if I have

```
function routine(n){
   function subroutine(n){
      return n+1;
   }
   return subroutine(n*n);
}
```

Is `subroutine` recreated each time I call `routine`?

Then, should I use

```
var routine = (function(){
   function subroutine(n){
      return n+1;
   }
   return function(n){
      subroutine(n*n);
   }
})();
```

instead?

Comment: *"Is subroutine recreated each time I call routine?"* Yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is created multiple times. You can check more info [here](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/stop-nesting-functions-but-not-all-of-them/)

Comment: Thanks, very interesting article. But I think that browsers should optimize it not recreating inner functions each time if they don't use any argument of the outer one.

Comment: @Oriol Why bother? If there are any local variables inside of `routine`, they should be available in the `subroutine` scope too, so that narrows down the type of function you're talking about. That's such a small percentage of functions that it wouldn't make sense for browsers to check for it. Basically, the only thing a browser could optimize is if the contents of `routine` is **only** a function...in which case, it's trivial for the `routine` function to be a function in the first place...

Comment: javascript is not even bothering to practically optimize tail recursion.

Comment: Well they *do* optimize this case and the code is not recreated. But the function objects (which get GCed thereafter) are.

Comment: @Ian Ah, you're right. I should have said "inner functions that don't use any variable of the outer one", I've updated the question. And I don't think they are such a small percentage, I have used them lots of times (but of course they are a minority).

Comment: @Bergi Could you explain a little more, please? What's GC?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is create multiple times.

Why can't you just use:

```
function routine(n){
   return function (n){
      return (n*n)+1;
   };
}
```

Or:

```
function routine(n){
   return (n*n)+1;
}
```

Or was that just an example?

Comment: what is the performance gain of this? and it returns function instead of value.

Comment: That does a different thing?

Comment: It was just a simplified example. In this case, of course it would be better to use `function routine(n){ return n*n+1; }`

Comment: This still creates a new function each time *and* it doesn't do the same as the `routine` function in the question.

Comment: It does the same thing. But it saves you from declaring two functions. Instead of using `subroutine(n*n);` in the return function. You can simply make an equivalent return function. In general, the performance different is minimal. @Oriol I decided to still include a function just in case this script was actually going to be used and they need to add more into the function. But good thinking.

Comment: @RobH What is mine doing different?

Comment: @Shawn31313 yours is returning a function. The one in the question returns the *result* of calling an inner function